# How to get claims of logged in user in Salesforce iOS SDK

Tags: community, oauth2, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, oauth, ios

I have integrated "SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS-Distribution" library in my iOS native application from this link to achieve  scenario as mentioned below

> https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS-Distribution

```
1) I have a HOME screen in my iOS native application.
2) From there I have to navigate to Salesforce login screen.
3) User will enter credentials and Salesforce will validate it.
4) Once logged in success then it will back to my HOME screen with token/sessionID.
5) That token/sessionID I will use internally in my application.
```

in my application I implemented code like

```
- (IBAction)login:(UIButton*)sender {

    NSString *strClientID = @"2kN3Bn17hv5A1f.3QFK.....";
    NSString *strCallbackURI = @"https://localhost:0000/signin-salesforce";

    NSString *kIdentifier = @"com.salesforce.ios";

    SFOAuthCredentials *creds = [[SFOAuthCredentials alloc] initWithIdentifier:kIdentifier clientId:strClientID encrypted:YES];
    creds.redirectUri = strCallbackURI;

    _oauthCoordinator = [[SFOAuthCoordinator alloc] initWithCredentials:creds];
    // _oauthCoordinator.scopes = [NSSet setWithObjects: @"web", nil]; /* If I pass scopes then I'm getting "Invalid scopes even I enabled same scopes in salesforce as a connected app" */
    _oauthCoordinator.delegate = self;
    [_oauthCoordinator authenticate];
}

#pragma mark - SFOAuthCoordinatorDelegate

- (void)oauthCoordinator:(SFOAuthCoordinator *)manager didBeginAuthenticationWithView:(UIWebView *)webView {

    CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y +=64;
    webView.frame = newFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}

- (void)oauthCoordinatorDidAuthenticate:(SFOAuthCoordinator *)coordinator authInfo:(SFOAuthInfo *)info
{
    [self.oauthCoordinator.view removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"authType = %d",info.authType);
    NSLog(@"accessToken = %@",coordinator.credentials.accessToken);
    NSLog(@"refreshToken = %@",coordinator.credentials.refreshToken);
    NSLog(@"instanceUrl = %@",[coordinator.credentials.instanceUrl description]);
    NSLog(@"issuedAt = %@",[coordinator.credentials.issuedAt descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);
    NSLog(@"userId = %@",coordinator.credentials.userId);
    NSLog(@"organizationId = %@",coordinator.credentials.organizationId);
    NSLog(@"communityId = %@",coordinator.credentials.communityId);
    NSLog(@"legacyIdentityInformation = %@",coordinator.credentials.legacyIdentityInformation);
    NSLog(@"activationCode = %@",coordinator.credentials.activationCode);
}

- (void)oauthCoordinator:(SFOAuthCoordinator *)coordinator didFailWithError:(NSError *)error authInfo:(SFOAuthInfo *)info
{

    [self.oauthCoordinator.view removeFromSuperview];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %d", error.code]
                                                    message:error.localizedDescription
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

Output log
2014-12-19 12:55:45.946 SampeSalesforce[24576:607] authType = 1
2014-12-19 12:55:45.947 SampeSalesforce[24576:607] accessToken = MAQOGHGMlDR.keKCErM5MAIHJI65S5ABF646DBB89AB767FBAB77575l2Dbf4Z6UkdYnE8x70BoXLzP
2014-12-19 12:55:45.948 SampeSalesforce[24576:607] refreshToken = (null)
2014-12-19 12:55:45.948 SampeSalesforce[24576:607] instanceUrl = (null)
2014-12-19 12:55:45.948 SampeSalesforce[24576:607] issuedAt = (null)
2014-12-19 12:55:45.948 SampeSalesforce[24576:607] userId = (null)
2014-12-19 12:55:45.948 SampeSalesforce[24576:607] organizationId = (null)
2014-12-19 12:55:45.949 SampeSalesforce[24576:607] communityId = (null)
2014-12-19 12:55:45.949 SampeSalesforce[24576:607] legacyIdentityInformation = (null)
```

I could able to logged in and getting "accessToken" but I need get claims of logged in user such as first name, last name, email etc...
 How can I get these info? is there anyway to get it by calling RestAPI? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

SFIdentityData provides all this information after the user is authenticated. For example to get First name of the user, you can use: [SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager].idCoordinator.idData.firstName;

Comment: @Ahhilesh, thank you for reply. Yes I know that SFAuthenticationManager  will hold the user account information. But in my code as showing above am not using "SFAuthenticationManager" class  anywhere. Can you please help me how to use it? am using "SFOAuthCoordinator" class for login. When I use "SFAuthenticationManager" class then I'm getting error says "error=invalid_scope&error_description=the requested scope is not available."

Comment: Make sure you're specifying at least `api` and `refresh_token` in your server-side Connected App configuration.  Mobile SDK apps need these scopes at a minimum to connect to Salesforce.  I'm guessing you're missing the `refresh_token` scope in your server-side configuration.

The [Mobile SDK Development Guide](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/blob/master/doc/mobile_sdk.pdf?raw=true) is a good resource for getting started with your Mobile SDK-based apps.

Answer (score 0):

Which SDK version are you using? You should use the latest SDK version 3.0. And use SalesforceSDKManager to initiate the OAuth.

Comment: I think am using latest SDK version 3.0, I downloaded from this link https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS-Distribution , there they are code snippet like __weak AppDelegate *weakSelf = self;
[SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].postLaunchAction = ^(SFSDKLaunchAction launchActionList) {
    [weakSelf setupRootViewController];
}; but I don't know what they have written in "setupRootViewController" method.

Comment: setupViewController is your method that you want to execute after authentication is successful. You have to implement setupViewController in your AppDelegate. Checkout an example in the SDK sample app: http://bit.ly/1Cq08O8